# How do I print all elements in set?

Tags: c++, set

I have trouble printing out elements in set.

```
std::set<triple, Compare> edges;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator j = graph[i].begin(); j != graph[i].end(); j++)
                edges.insert(makeTriple((*j).second, i, (*j).first));

        for (std::set<triple, Compare>::iterator j = edges.begin(); j != edges.end(); j++)
            printf("%d and %d\n\n", (*j).first + 1, (*j).second + 1);
```

Only 7 elements  are printed of of 13. 
Compare function looks like:

```
bool operator()(const triple &a, const triple &b) const
    {
        if (a.distance == b.distance && a.first == b.first)
            return (a.second < b.second);
        if (a.distance == b.distance && a.second == b.second)
            return (a.first < b.first);
        return (a.distance < b.distance);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect your problem isn't with "printing". Rather, it's with managing a comparator that properly enforces a strict weak order. Print the size of you `edges` container after each iteration of your insertion. Think about what the results are when `distance` members are equal, and *neither* `first` nor `second` members are equal. The result is *always* `false`, which is broken.

Comment: How can I fix it? Whenever the distances are the same, the size of a set doesn`t change.

Comment: One more hint: Try nesting your `if`s instead of checking multiple things in the statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) function does not fulfill the requirement

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying `Compare`, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and `false` otherwise.

The most obvious fix would be:

```
bool operator()(const triple &a, const triple &b) const {
    if (a.distance == b.distance) {
        if(a.first == b.first)  return a.second < b.second;
        else                    return a.first < b.first;
    } else                      return a.distance < b.distance;
}
```

This can however be done simpler with [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) from `<tuple>`:

```
bool operator()(const triple &a, const triple &b) const {
    return
        std::tie(a.distance, a.first, a.second) < std::tie(b.distance, b.first, b.second);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/khj__Q)

Answer (score 1):

**The printing is fine**: it shows you what is in the set.  A shorter version could be:

```
   for (auto j = edges.begin(); j != edges.end(); j++)
        printf("%d and %d\n\n", j->first + 1, j->second + 1);
```

or even:

```
   for (auto e: edges)
        cout << e.first+1 <<" and "<< e.second+1<<endl<<endl;
```

**The problem is in the comparator**.  At the insertion, the set compares the element that you want to insert to the elements already in the set. If there is some  "equality" (based on your comparator), the element is not inserted.

Your symptoms tell us that your comparator doesn't meet the **[compare requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)** of the standard library, which is a strict weak ordering.

You can easily test it yourself and compare your different triples. If you take `Compare comp;`, those that are `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)` are considered equal.

Take the following triplets (`distance, first, second)`: for a `(1, 2, 3)` and for b `(1,3, 2)`. You can easily  `!comp(a,b)&&!comp(b,a)` turns to !(1<1)&&!(1<1) which is true.  So se set would consider them as equal and only one of the two would be in your end results.

**How to correct it?**

You need to handle the case where the distances are equal but first is different and second is different.  So in the end, what matters the more, first or second ?

Assuming that it's first you could write:

```
bool operator()(const triple &a, const triple &b) const
{
    if (a.distance == b.distance && a.first == b.first)
        return (a.second < b.second);
    if (a.distance == b.distance)
        return (a.first < b.first);
    return (a.distance < b.distance);
}
```

or in a more [compact way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
bool operator()(const triple &a, const triple &b) const
{
    return tie(a.distance,a.first, a.second)< tie(b.distance,b.first, b.second);
}
```

*Unfortunately for you, the compact way is C++11 so if `auto` doesn't work at school, `tie` won't either*

Comment: Auto doesn't work well on Windows. I`m currently on Linux and it's fine, but tomorrow's exam will be on Windows.

Comment: @Vojin ok! This means that you have an older compiler and some other C++11 feature might not work either.